# Problem proving Cartan's identity

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

There is a famous identity stating that, if $X$ is a field and $\omega$ a form, then:

$$\mathcal{L}_X\omega=\iota_Xd\omega+d\iota_X\omega.$$

I'm trying to prove it. [Thanks to Anthony Carapetis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508304/interior-product-and-exterior-product), I know that:

$$\iota_X(\alpha\wedge\beta)=(k+\ell)(\iota_X\alpha\wedge\beta+(-1)^k\alpha\wedge\iota_X\beta),$$

where $\alpha$ is a $k$-form and $\beta$ an $\ell$-form. Now I start on Cartan. I first suppose $\omega=d\alpha$ for $\alpha$ a $(k-1)$-form. Then:

$$\mathcal{L}_Xd\alpha=d\mathcal{L}_X\alpha=d(d\iota_X\alpha+\iota_Xd\alpha)=d\iota_Xd\alpha=d\iota_X\omega,$$

and being $\omega$ exact, it is closed, so $\iota_Xd\omega=\iota_X0=0$. Now consider $f\omega$ for any smooth function $f$. $f$ will then be a 0-form. If I try induction, I get stuck with:

$$\mathcal{L}_X(f\omega)=f\mathcal{L}_X\omega+\mathcal{L}_Xf\cdot\omega=fd\iota_X\omega+\iota_Xdf\cdot\omega,$$

whereas the RHS of Cartan would be:

\begin{align*}
d\iota_X(f\omega)+\iota_Xd(f\omega)={}&d(kf\iota_X\omega)+\iota_X(df\wedge\omega)={} \\
{}={}&kdf\wedge\iota_X\omega+kfd\iota_X\omega+(k+1)\iota_Xdf\wedge\omega-(k+1)df\wedge\iota_X\omega,
\end{align*}

and those coefficients get in the way, because the two sides only equate for $k=1$. Am I doing something wrong? Have I used the linked question too hastily to deduce a formula for the normalized wedge?

**Details**

Anthony proved, in his answer, that, if $\overline\wedge$ denotes the unnormalized antisimmetrization, then:

$$\iota_X(\alpha\overline\wedge\beta)=k\iota_X\alpha\overline\wedge\beta+(-1)^k\ell\beta\overline\wedge\iota_X\beta.$$

The relationship between $\wedge$ and $\overline\wedge$ is that, if $\alpha$ is a $k$-form and $\beta$ an $\ell$-form:

$$\alpha\wedge\beta=\frac{(k+\ell)!}{k!\ell!}\alpha\overline\wedge\beta.$$

The above identity then becomes:

$$\iota_X\left(\frac{k!\ell!}{(k+\ell)!}\alpha\wedge\beta\right)=\frac{(k-1)!\ell!}{(k+\ell-1)!}k\iota_X\alpha\wedge\beta+(-1)^k\frac{k!(\ell-1)!}{(k+\ell-1)!}\ell\alpha\wedge\iota_X\beta,$$

which with due simplifications done after extracting the fraction from the parenthesis on the left yields:

$$\frac{1}{k+\ell}\iota_X(\alpha\wedge\beta)=\iota_X\alpha\wedge\beta+(-1)^k\alpha\wedge\iota_X\beta,$$

which is almost identical to what I said at the start of the question after the link to my previous question. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I think the normalization factor should just be $1/(k! l!)$. For example Spivak has $\omega \wedge \eta = (k+l)!/k!l! \;{\rm Alt}(\omega \otimes \eta)$ but his ${\rm Alt}$ includes the normalization factor of $1/(k+l)!$. If you use this definition then you get the nice Leibniz formula for the interior product without the coefficients.

Comment: I got the coefficient off Lee, perhaps I didn't read what his Alt was :). Indeed, all problems come from that $(k+\ell)!$ in the normalization, so removing it fixes everything.

Comment: Indeed Lee does like Spivak with his Alt including the normalization factor.

Comment: Another method: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480545/proving-cartans-magic-formula-using-homotopy

Comment: @JohnMa OMG!!! What is that?? No really, it looks so damn complex, much shorter to just fix a normalization and proceed my way :). Interesting reference anyway. Admitting one knows about homotopy -- and I fear path homotopy is not enough, and higher-dimension homotopies are total strangers to me :).

Comment: Moving to the integral picture is not so strange - both kinds of derivatives occuring here are very well-behaved under integrals, and after all differential forms are made to be integrated! Even if it is not easier I think this kind of proof is usually more enlightening than a local computation - integration is where the real geometric meaning of $\mathcal L$ and $d$ show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anthony noted in his comment, correcting the normalization coefficient by eliminating the denominator $(k+\ell)!$ removes the problem and yields:

$$\iota_X(\alpha\wedge\beta)=\iota_X\alpha\wedge\beta+(-1)^k\alpha\wedge\iota_X\beta,$$

which allows for Cartan to be proved my way.

Another way is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480545/proving-cartans-magic-formula-using-homotopy), which John Ma posted in his comment, but which is out of my way because it uses homotopy of chains and I have left homotopy as path homotopy.

I'm posting this to get this question answered.